# Prevent LESS includes from transpiling to CSS in PHPStorm

Tags: less, phpstorm, code-translation

normally I use SCSS, which my PHPStorm IDE transpiles into nice css for me. I use a lot of includes, which in SCSS if you use an underscore as a prefix (eg _layout.scss) the transpiler recognises that this is going to be an include, so doesn't transpile it.

So I've started using LESS, but it doesn't have this same rule. Every LESS file gets transpiled, whether it uses an underscore prefix or not. But this bugs me, because there's unnecessary css files in my project, which gets annoying mostly when I search.

So my question is, is there a standard prefix I can use in LESS which won't transpile the file?

Comment: Show you watcher settings for LESS

Comment: please try enabling 'track only root files' file watcher option - does it help?